# How to handle date time formats and cultures

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, datetime

By default I am setting the website's culture as follows:

System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-CA");

So it is now expecting dd/MM/YY

In an input box (it has a jquery date picker), we allow users to enter a date.  With the datepicker, we have to have a format like:

MM/dd/YY   e.g. 02/18/2014

So what is now happening is if someone was to set a date as:  02/12/2014

It is being set in the database, but then when the datepicker renders the date is is Dec. 02, 2014.

How should I fix this? i.e at what level and how

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be solved at client end, *(and would be more user friendly, IMO)*. You can specify the date format for the [jQuery Datepicker](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#date-formats) like:

```
$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker( "option", "dateFormat", "dd/MM/yyyy" );
```

So if the user picks a date it will be displayed in format `dd/MM/yyyy`. Its `SelectedValue` returns you Javascript `Date` object and that can be passed to server side. No parsing would be required.

Comment: +1: it **has** to be solved at the client end: the server side has no idea of the client's *locale*/*culture*...unless you ask the user for that information.

Comment: can I set the jqeury validation date format also somehow?

Answer (score 0):

> With the datepicker, we have to have a format like:  `MM/dd/YY` e.g. `02/18/2014`

Does the datepicker give you a *string* or a *date*?  If it's a date just leave it as a date.  If it's a string convert it to a date and *specify the format*:

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.Parse(dateString, "MM/dd/yyyy");
```

Same when setting the date - if the datepicker expects a string in a particular format then *use that format*:

```
datePicker.Value = dt.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
```